Is Jupiter wealthy at the end of the movie?
Jupiter Ascending (2015) ends with Jupiter being the owner of Earth (and maybe more, I am not sure because what she becomes at the end was confusing to me - but presumably the head of Abrasax).
She was supposed to have "wealth beyond her imagination" (I think that is what Kalique said), but how does this work on Earth? Aside from taking ownership of the Earth by force, she is nobody. She still works as a cleaner (why?) and no special "wealth" seems to have arisen from her new position.
As a side note, the wealth of Abrasax may simply collapse because I doubt Jupiter would be willing to support the crops.

Wealthy people don't usually spend their days doing poorly-paid scutwork.
